How to rotate face groups individually around their centers (geometry nodes)
Using geometry nodes I split an Ico Sphere into face groups using the 'Face Group Boundaries' node and a 'Voronoi Texture' node, but I can't figure out a way to rotate each face group around its center position.
I tried using 'Evaluate at Index' to get the position of each face group using their indices, then plugging that into 'Vector Rotate' center, but when changing the angle value it's clearly not rotating around the individual center positions.
Is there a way to do this in geometry nodes?



Your blue frame can look like this:

See:
How do I average values in a field per ID with Geometry Nodes?

wow that was fast, thanks a lot .. I actually tried messing around with Accumulate Field but couldn't figure out what to use for the inputs, I'll be using this averaging method a lot, thanks again!
